# bash parameter expansion within a scalar variable via echo

Tags: bash, echo, variable-expansion, brace-expansion

title: bash parameter expansion within a scalar variable

I have a bash script which runs a diff between two files.
If there is a diff, I want it to print statement1 and statement2
They are long so i put them into variables, but the echo statement
will not expand the parameter.
Can this be done in bash?

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

source="/home/casper"
target="data/scripts"
statement1="There is a change in ${i}, please check the file"
statement2="or cp /home/casper/${i} /data/scripts/$i"

for i in file1 file2l file3 file4 file5  ; do
    sleep 1 ;
    if diff $source/$i $target/$i 2>&1 > /dev/null ; then
        echo " "
    else
        echo "$statement1 "
        echo "$statement2 "
    fi
done
exit 0
```

The script seems to work - it finds a diff when it needs to find one.
However this is what it prints out.

```
There is a change in , please check the file
or cp /home/casper/ data/scripts/
```

I want it to say

```
There is a change in file2, please check the file
or cp /home/casper/file2 /data/scripts/file2
```

Comment: Replace `2>&1 > /dev/null` by `> /dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: Replace your first and second `${i}` by `\${i}`.

Comment: Note that `source` is also the name of a command. I would recommend using `src` for your variable name instead. Also, if you are not accessing each `statement` variable more than once, why not just avoid the use of the variables altogether? e.g. `echo "There is a change in ${i}, please check the file"` which would work.

Comment: `bash` variables and command names exist in different namespaces. Something like `source=foo.sh; source "$source"`, while potentially confusing, works just fine.

Comment: As an aside, you want `diff -q` and take out the redirections.  Redirecting error output is often a very bad idea -- there is a reason error messages are being printed to a different file descriptor in the first place.

Comment: Triplee - that is a very good aside.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$i` is expanded when you define `statement1` and `statement2`, not when you expand them. Use a shell function to output the text.

```
notification () {
    echo "There is a change in $1, please check the file"
    echo "or cp /home/casper/$1 /data/scripts/$1"
}

source="/home/casper"
target="data/scripts"
for i in file1 file2l file3 file4 file5  ; do
    sleep 1 ;
    if diff "$source/$i" "$target/$i" 2>&1 > /dev/null ; then
        echo " "
    else
        notification "$i"
    fi
done
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `eval`:

```
TEMPLATE_MSG="aaa \${VALUE} ccc"
...
VALUE="bbb"
eval echo "${TEMPLATE_MSG}"
```

But I don't recommend it, because `eval` is evil :-) Other option is using pattern substitution:

```
TEMPLATE_MSG="aaa @1@ ccc"
...
VALUE="bbb"
echo "${TEMPLATE_MSG/@1@/${VALUE}}"
```

So you put some unique pattern in your message (e.g. `@1@`) and then, when you print the message, you replace it with the content of variable.